# Cloud.Typography web font characters not recognised in Firefox/Safari

Tags: css, browser, encoding, webfonts, cloud.typography

I am experiencing problems when using the suggested Typography.com font implementation for the font ‘Gotham Rounded SSm A’.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cloud.typography.com/6035272/698322/css/fonts.css" />
```

The font seems to render correctly in both Chrome and Internet Explorer 9, however both Firefox and Safari seem to ignore certain characters – falling back to ‘Verdana’ in the font stack. [image]

I have crawled the web searching for a similar result but couldn't find anything. Any advice would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to follow the instructions cloud.typograhy.com gives: for font-family you are required to give two options. For example on my site I have to use:

font-family: 'Knockout 27 A', 'Knockout 27 B';

If you give just the first Firefox wont display certain characters. I had to find this one out myself. Typography.com didn't answer my supprt question.

Hope this helps som

Answer (score 1):

Incase anyone is still interested in the solution. You have to include both Font names in your CSS.

For example:

```
font-family: 'Chronicle Display A', 'Chronicle Display B';
```

The character sets are split across A and B. No idea why but using both solves this problem.